# Play with scala - Injecting dependencies through an instance of Guice Injector

Tags: scala, playframework, guice

My application makes use of **Play-2.4.2/Scala-2.11.6** that comes with built-in Guice support for DI

All my DAOs bind an implementation to an interface as below , which is supposed to be the simplest way in Guice

```
@ImplementedBy(classOf[PersonDAOImpl])
trait PersonDAO {
}

class PersonDAOImpl @Inject()
(
(@NamedDatabase("mysql")protected val dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider,
 protected val cache : CacheApi) extends PersonDAO with SQLWrapper {
..
...

}
```

The above implementation does not need addition of any module to provide bindings.

Now for some reason, I **do not want to inject the dependencies into the constructor** of Books class **using @Inject annotation** . So , I tried injecting it as below

```
class Books {

  val injector = Guice.createInjector()

  val personDAO : PersonDAO = injector.getInstance(classOf[PersonDAOImpl])

..
...

}
```

But this throws me a guice configuration exception saying :

```
Caused by: com.google.inject.ConfigurationException: Guice configuration errors:

1) No implementation for play.api.cache.CacheApi was bound.
  while locating play.api.cache.CacheApi
    for parameter 1 at schema.PersonDAOImpl.<init>
  while locating PersonDAO

2)  No implementation for play.api.db.slick.DatabaseConfigProvider annotated with @play.db.NamedDatabase(value=mysql) was bound.
  while locating play.api.cache.CacheApi
    for parameter 2 at schema.PersonDAOImpl.<init>  while locating PersonDAO
```

What needs to be done now ? Is my approach right or wrong in this case ? Can someone help me out with this ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may want to use `play.api.Play.current.injector`

Comment: It worked !!! .. Thank you so much @cchantep ... you made my day !!

Comment: Could you please provide the comment as an answer and accept it? It's easier to see that this one is answered then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Injector](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.0/api/scala/index.html#play.api.inject.Injector) from the current Play [Application](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.0/api/scala/index.html#play.api.Application).

```
import play.api.{ Application, Play }
import play.api.inject.Injector

val currentApp: Application = Play.current
val injector: Injector = currentApp.injector
// in short play.api.Play.current.injector

// Then use the injector
import play.api.inject.ApplicationLifecycle
current.injector.instanceOf[ApplicationLifecycle].
  addStopHook { () => ??? }
```

(See example using `injector` with the [Play plugin for ReactiveMongo](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.11/documentation/tutorial/play2.html#play-24))

Comment: Given that `Play.current` is deprecated in Play 2.5, how do you do this now in 2.5?

Comment: @jon_wu did you find an answer on how to use  application injector in 2.5?

Comment: Either you use DI in the way Play supports it, or use deprecated injector (knowing to should have to be fixed later), or you directly init the MongoDriver by your self.